# dotnet Entity Framework INSERT SELECT FROM other table

Tags: sql, .net, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am not an expert on databases and SQL. I am developing a dotnet core application using the Entity Framework to access a (postgresql) database.
I have the following tables with the following columns:

```
Table: Log
Columns:
  Timestamp: timestamp without time zone
  Value: smallint
  Status: smallint
Table: Status
  ID: smallint
  Name: character varying(30)
```

When I insert a record/row in the Log table, I want to look up the ID belonging to the Name in the Status table and fill in the value in the Status column in the Log table. If the Name is not found, I want to insert -1 in the Status column.
I have implemented this as:

```
Status status = null;
try {
  status = context.Status.Single(a => a.Name == statusName);
} catch {}
var entry = new Log {
  Timestamp = timestamp,
  Value = value,
  Status = (status != null) ? status.Id : Convert.ToInt16(-1)
};
context.Log.Add(entry);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This works. I think it can be implemented more efficient. Also there are some issues with this implementation, I believe. For example when I temporary stop the database, the query for the status id fails and an insert with -1 is performed. When the database is restarted, the inserts are still performed (I think the Entity Framework cashes the actions), but with a -1 and not the correct value. When the insert can be executed as a single statement, I expect/hope that the right values will be inserted.
Therefor I would like to know a few things. These are my actual questions:

1. How can I achieve this using an SQL statement (on the database administration tool)?
2. How can I implement it, using the Entity Framework, such that a single SQL statement is executed on the database (and thereby inserting the correct data when the database is temporary shut down)?

Comment: This is usually achieved by creating a stored procedure in the database that does the work, then calling the stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a way to make one sql query to perform the lookup and execute the insert. I (only) managed to implement it using `ExecuteSqlRaw`.

```
string sqlText = "INSERT INTO \"Log\" (\"Timestamp\", \"Value\", \"Status\") " +
                 "SELECT {0}, {1}, COALESCE(\"Stat\".\"ID\", -1) " +
                 "FROM \"Status\" AS \"Stat\" " +
                 "RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 'xxx' as CONSTANT) AS \"Dummy\" " +
                 "ON \"Stat\".\"Name\" = {2}";
int rows = 0;
try
{
  rows = context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sqlText, timestamp, value, status);
  if (rows != 1)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Error writing status log to database: rows returned is {0}", rows);
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Error writing status log to database: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Although this works, I went for another solution. Since the Status table does not hold a large list, I load the table into a dictionary in memory and lookup the ID in there for every record that has to be added.

```
statusValues = context.Status.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Name, kvp => kvp.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

ad 2) implement it as single statement is *not recommended* ; reason is using code, that should be run as async. Better it **two separate steps** like this:

```cs
// step 1: load data from DB
var status = await context.Status.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Name == statusName);
if(status == null)
{
   // warning or error
}

// step 2: create new one or more instances + Save back to DB
context.Log.Add(new Log
{
   Timestamp = timestamp,
   Value = value,
   Status = (status != null) ? status.Id : Convert.ToInt16(-1)
};
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I am a bit confused. This is "almost" what I have. I do not get the following from your proposal/solution: do you propose to handle the result of the SingleOrDefault differently than I was doing?

Comment: Secondly, although doing it in 2 steps might be the better implementation. Do you "know" the answer to my original questions? (I am also trying to learn:) )

Comment: My Answer is better way in language C#, async and remove catch {} which should be issue in debugging. If you ask for more efficient way as faster for SQL DB yep, it can be  implemented by direct SQL command as raw syntax, stored procedure a trivial call from c# or possibly as Bulk operation.